Android styles.xml in Dark Mode overrides .Net Maui Splash Theme styles
I created a .Net MAUI application that has a native Android DatePicker. In the directory Platforms/Android/Resources I have two folders, values and values-night for the styles.xml of the Android DatePicker on light mode and on dark mode respectively which are very similar except for the colors they set. However, when I include the styles.xml in values-night, it seems that it is overriding other styles of the Maui.SplashTheme, causing the UI outside of the datepicker to have unwanted changes when the android device is set to dark mode. This is the code I currently have:
values/styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources> 
    <style name="Maui.MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">  
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/CustomDatePickerDialog</item>  
    </style> 

    <style name="CustomDatePickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
         <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>  
         <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>  
         <item name="android:colorBackground">#0000ff</item>  
    </style> 
</resources>

values-night/styles.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources> 
    <style name="Maui.MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">  
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/CustomDatePickerDialog</item>  
    </style> 

    <style name="CustomDatePickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
         <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>  
         <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>  
         <item name="android:colorBackground">#00ffff</item>  
    </style> 
</resources>

and including it in my MainActivity like this
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]

The DatePicker is created on a .xaml page (for example) as:
<DatePicker MinimumDate="01/01/2022"
            MaximumDate="12/31/2022"
            Date="06/21/2022" />

I have implemented solutions such as the ones provided in this post but none seem to fix the unwanted changes on dark mode. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Additionally, is there a way to switch between light and dark mode for android in .Net MAUI, rather than just obtaining it from the system settings?

causing the UI outside of the datepicker to have unwanted changes when the android device is set to dark mode.  Can you elaborate on what changes have resulted in? And could you please post more code snippets so that we can try to reproduce the problem on our side?

@JessieZhang-MSFT By causing changes outside of the UI, I mean that it capitalizes all text on buttons, blurs the background of various components, etc for the entire application. I added a new update to the post to assist in reproducing the issue.

You need to change the Maui.SplashTheme to Maui.MainTheme in [Activity]
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]

And please make sure the buildaction of values-night/styles.xml and values/styles.xml are Android resources.
I tested it, it is working in my side.

This does not solve the issue at all. I am using Maui.SplashTheme to style my splash screen. Switching to Maui.MainTheme completely removes all of those styles and it does not fix the problem of the outside UI being modified

Well, this solved my issue.  Not changing Maui.SplashTheme, but the reminder to make "styles.xml" be an Android Resource.   Thanks

I don't even have Android Resource as a drop down menu item for build action? Do you mean embedded resource?
